# sending JSON using simple RKClient post

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to send a request using RestKit. I want it to be sent in JSON, but it seems that default post methot from RKClient uses some kind of FORM data formatting (I check it using [request HTTPBodyString]).

I need to send the data using simple POST, like this (I'm not using object mapping):

```
[[RKClient sharedClient] post:path usingBlock:^(RKRequest* req) {
    req.params = params;
    req.delegate = self;
}];
```

I found some solutions that use NSJSONSerialization, but that method crashes when I put NSDate object in my JSON dictionary.

Is there a way to tell the RKClient to send requests using JSON?

**Update:** params is a NSDictionary. I want to be able to tell RestKit to serialize my dictionary using JSON when sending it by POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the RestKit's [serializationMIMEType](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/serializationMIMEType) property to **RKMIMETypeJSON**.

E.g.

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

see also http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html:

> The desired serialization format is configured by setting the
>   serializationMIMEType property. RestKit currently supports
>   serialization to RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded and RKMIMETypeJSON.

**Update**:

Example for posting a plain JSON String with the correct Mime Type:

```
RKParams *params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                        MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client post:@"/mypath"
                                      params:params
                                    delegate:self];
```

**Update 2:**

Getting JSON from a NSDictionary object:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myNSDictionaryObject
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for simple POSTs like the example in my question (only for serializing objects)

Comment: That's not true. I am posting a plain JSON string with it. See my example above.

Comment: Yeah, but how do you get jsonString? The question is: does RestKit offer simple method for sending json serialized data via POST when I provide just a NSDictionary?

Comment: For this you can use NSJSONSerialization offered by iOS. See my update above.

Comment: As I stated in my question I know that I can use NSJSONSerialization. So I guess it is not possible in RestKit to **automatically** send JSONs using RKClient post?